# Mongo Projection is not working for SubFields

Tags: java, mongodb, projection, morphia

I have a json object something like this. I want to exclude the field "**placeOfBirth**" from the response. For that I am using projection. But somehow it is working only for fileds but not for the subfields. So **placeofBirth** is never excluded but **status** is removed in the response.
Here is my code

```java
Projection projectionExclude = Projection.of().exclude("subObject.placeOfBirth").exclude("status");

 MorphiaCursor<T> cursor = datastore.aggregate(T.class)
            .match(Filters.eq("about", id))
            .project(projectionExclude).execute(T.class);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.hasNext()){
      result = cursor.toList().get(0);
    }
```

Json data

```json
{
"about: " "testing/123",
"subObject" : [
  {
    "about" : "subobject/123",
   "placeOfBirth": {
         "birth": ["Lisbon"] 
                 }
  }
 ],
"status" : "approved"
}
```

How can make this work? Is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This actually works for me on 2.2.  Here's the test I'm running:

```java
MongoCollection<Document> collection = getDocumentCollection(User.class);
collection.insertOne(parse("{'about': 'testing/123', 'subObject' : [ {'about' : 'subobject/123', 'placeOfBirth': {'birth': " +
                           "['Lisbon']}}],'status' : 'approved'}"));

Document next = getDs().aggregate(User.class)
                       .match(eq("about", "testing/123"))
                       .project(project()
                                    .exclude("subObject.placeOfBirth")
                                    .exclude("status"))
                       .execute(Document.class)
                       .next();

assertFalse(next.toJson().contains("placeOfBirth"));
assertFalse(next.toJson().contains("status"));
```